# FontForge Script: how to add kerning between two glyphs to a font

Tags: fontforge

I would like to add kerning between the letter A and itself so that the two letters stack on top of each other, over many font files.

How would I achieve this using a FontForge script?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script to add kerning between the letter A and itself to a font that previously had no kerning table:

(1) Open your font

```
Open($1);
```

(2) Add a lookup with the gpos_pair type, and "kern" as feature, then create a subtable inside

```
AddLookup("kern","gpos_pair",0,[["kern",[["latn",["dflt"]]]]]); 
AddLookupSubtable("kern","kern-1");
```

(3) Select your first glyph by name

```
Select("A");
```

(4) Add kerning from this glyph to another glyph:

```
AddPosSub("kern-1",GlyphInfo("Name"),0,0,-2883,0,0,0,0,0);
```

(5) Generate your font

```
Generate($1:r + "-kerned.ttf");
```

I am adding this here because I could not find a single example of AddPosSub for character pairs (and it is really difficult to figure out where all the 0 should go without randomly trying.